# eXosip2 function missed?

Tags: sip, voip, exosip

I am writing a software for an embedded device, the basic function is VoIP, now I want to implement the SIP using eXosip2. I have downloaded the libeXosip2-3.6.0 source code from http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/exosip/

I checked a few example code and find that to send an INVITE message, I need to call:
`eXosip_call_build_initial_invite` (in eXcall_api.c)

In this function, it will call `osip_to_init` , `osip_to_parse` , `osip_to_free` etc functions, however I could not find these functions in the eXosip2 folder....why?

Actually I also downloaded the osip2 library, I can find these functions, but can not see them in the eXosip2. Are these functions included in some object files that I can not read the content? Or actually I need to include both the osip2 and eXosip2?

I am sorry if this is a trivial question, I am novice to programming and would be very thankful if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also build libosip2. Then link libeXosip2 to the libosip2 libraries

Answer (score 0):

To be complete, you need to download [libosip-3.6.0](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/osip/) and install it with those commands line (on a linux/unix platform):

```
$> tar -xvzf libosip-0.X.X.tar.gz
$> mkdir linux-build
$> cd linux-build
$> ../libosip-0.X.X/configure
$> make
# make install
```

Then compilation of eXosip2 should work.
The same is true for newer versions.